# convert all JSON columns into new table

Tags: mysql, sql, json, json-query

I currently have a table structured like:

```
customer_id  name   phoneNumbers  
1            Adam   [{'type':'home','number':'687-5309'} , {'type':'cell','number':'123-4567'}] 
2            Bill   [{'type':'home','number':'987-6543'}]
```

With the phoneNumbers column set as a JSON column type.
For simplicity sake though I am wanting to covert all the JSON phone numbers into a new separate table. 
Something like:

```
phone_id  customer_id type    number
1         1           home    687-5309  
2         1           cell    123-4567
3         2           home    987-6543
```

It seems like it should be do-able with OPENJSON but so far I haven't had any luck in figuring out how to declare it correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: OPENJSON is a function in Microsoft SQL Server, but you tagged your question [tag:mysql]. Which database brand are you using?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB . I didn't realize OPENJSON was Microsoft SQL Server exclusive. Is there a MariaDB alternative?

Comment: I don't use MariaDB. Your question seems like it would be easy to answer by looking at their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

USE recursive CTE with 1 and recurse upto json_length.

```
SELECT c.*, JSON_LENGTH(c.phoneNumbers) as json_length
from customers c;
```

then use concat to pass that element_id in Extract Query:

```
(json_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(phoneNumbers, CONCAT('$.type.',1))), json_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(phoneNumbers, CONCAT('$.number.',1))))
(json_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(phoneNumbers, CONCAT('$.type.',2))), json_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(phoneNumbers, CONCAT('$.number.',1))))
-
-
-
(json_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(phoneNumbers, CONCAT('$.type.',json_length))), json_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(phoneNumbers, CONCAT('$.number.',json_length))))
```

Comment: I've never heard of CTE until now, but it does look like it will work. But I'm not sure I follow the code you posted. I have created a dbfiddle here, with as far I can figure: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f9e62743d554b71a355156de0a7c2a21

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I'm at a road block. Any additional help you can give would be great.

Comment: Please get latest answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT id,
    name,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(phone, CONCAT("$[", seq.i, "]", ".", "number"))) AS NUMBER, 
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(phone, CONCAT("$[", seq.i, "]", ".", "type"))) AS TYPE
FROM customer, (SELECT 0 AS I UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS seq
WHERE seq.i < json_length(phone)
```

The trick is `(SELECT 0 as i union all SELECT 1)`, depends on your JSON array's length you may need to add more index. You can find out the max length by:

```
SELECT MAX(JSON_LENGTH(phone)) FROM customer;
```

Comment: Awesome that seems to be working. I'll be breaking this down to figure out how it works. Thanks for the example.

Comment: Actually after playing around a bit, it doesn't quite seem to be work (or I can't get it to work). I expanded the numbers to include 1 more and it still only selects 3 results (Should be 4). dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ab04c3a223b5151fdc2f095b36ad9318

Comment: Sorry, I did not make myself clear enough. You need to add more `union all select index` to match the length of the array, should be: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=22b40f360115b99a0e33faf369e94d2a

Comment: Gotcha. That makes more sense, but so if I have lets say 200 (exaggeration) phone numbers, I would just keep adding UNION ALL to the query. I know you mentioned before getting the max length. Is that possible for this type of query? I was able to get something working here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8a415e2b968b8d63085dd13521517910 but it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

Please change CTE defination syntax according to MySQL\Maria versions.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_recurse_json AS
(
  SELECT customer_id, phone_numbers, 0 as recurse, JSON_LENGTH(c.phoneNumbers) as json_length, 
            json_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(phoneNumbers, CONCAT('$[',0,'].type'))) as type, 
            json_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(phoneNumbers, CONCAT('$[',0,'].number'))) as number
  FROM table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.customer_id, t.phone_numbers, ct.recurse + 1 as recurse, t.json_length, 
            json_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(ct.phoneNumbers, CONCAT('$[',ct.recurse,'].type'))) as type, 
            json_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(ct.phoneNumbers, CONCAT('$[',ct.recurse,'].number'))) as number
  FROM TABLE t
  INNER JOIN cte_recurse_json ct ON t.customer_id = ct.customer_id
  WHERE ct.recurse < json_length
)
SELECT customer_id, type, number FROM cte_recurse_json;
```